# How to receive json field in Django Rest Framework which I don't want to store?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm building an api with Django Rest Framework for the following json:

```
{
    "x_id": 123,
    "message_type": "count",
    "aggregate": [{"id": 1, "count": 3}],
}
```

The json objects in the aggregate can be of two different types, which is dependent on the `message_type`. So if `message_type` equals `count` the objects in the aggregate array look like above, and if the `message_type` equals `person` then the object in the aggregate array are completely different.

I've got two separate models for the two different types of aggregates and I want to store them in those tables depending on the `message_type`. But since `message_type` is not part of any model it isn't validated and I can't use it in the serializers `create()` method:

```
class ObservationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Observation
        fields = ['x_id']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print("message_type" in validated_data)  # => prints "False"
        return Observation.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Does anybody know how I can make the field `message_type` required, just so that I can use it to decide in which table I want to store the aggregate?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use `message_type` as GET parameter.

```
class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = '__all__'


class BSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = B
        fields = '__all__'
```

The view should looks like this

```
class MyView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      message_type = request.GET.get('message_type', None)
      if message_type is not None:

          if message_type == 'count':
              serializer = ASerializer(data=request.data)
          if message_type == 'person':
              serializer = BSerializer(data=request.data)

          if serializer.is_valid():
              serializer.save()
          return Response(status=HTTP_200_OK)
      return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Request looks like

```
POST /api/view-path/?message_type=count or /api/view-path/?message_type=person
{
  # Post body fields... 
}
```